# Access-Control-Allow-Headers in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am using MEAN stack with AngularJS. I am trying to get a JSON value from URL HTTP GET method from the controller but I am not able to get it. I am facing an error like this in browser console

**Request header field If-Modified-Since is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

#### Controller

```
  $http({
    method: "GET", url: /json url/
  }).then(function (response) {
    $scope.Content = response;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was learning MEAN, I got the same error. I fixed it as below. Hope it will helps you.

In your app, server side (Node.Js) Index.js, 
Import CORS module, (get it from npm)

```
const cors = require("cors");
```

and simply use it.

```
// Enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing
app.use(cors());
```

and try to set some of these headers depends on your requirement

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,POST,PUT");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

No need of Extra headers from Client side. Just a $http.get() will give you the response.

For more information read this standard article https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-cors-protocol

Comment: still i am facing same pblm @sk smart

Comment: At that time it was worked for me. anyways, I have updated my answer. Please try once again.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this one helps...!

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization');
});
```

Comment: after i paste this code my project server start but my html page not loading

Comment: check any error in the console or make default route in the client side (AngularJs)